# Programmatic Navigation with vue-router produces a error

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

i creating a SPA with vue.js, in the form component want that when finish submit redirect to list component but happen that Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.

I do not know why this error occurs if someone could correct my code, I would appreciate a clear explanation that I am doing wrong

```
<template>
    <div class="row center-element">
    <h1 class="pink-text center-align">{{title}}</h1>
    <form class="col s12 m12 " @submit.prevent="save">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix  light-blue-text">pets</i>
          <input id="name" type="text" class="validate" v-model="form.name">
          <label for="name">name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="file-field input-field col s12 m12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix  light-blue-text">image</i>
            <input  id='image' type="file">
          <div class="file-path-wrapper ">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row right-align">
        <button class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light light-blue " type="submit" name="action">
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
        <router-link to="/" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light light-blue ">
          <i class="material-icons right">cancel</i>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
        data() {
            return{
            title:'Create',
            store: '/admin/animals',
                    method: 'post',
                form:{},
                errors:'',
                msm:''

            }

        },
        beforeMount() {
            if(this.$route.meta.mode === 'edit') {
                this.title = 'Edit'
                this.form.name =  this.$route.params.name
                this.store = 'animals/' + this.$route.params.id
                this.method = 'post'
            }
        },  
        methods:{
            save(){
                let vm = this
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('name',this.form.name)
                formData.append('image',image.files[0])
          if (this.title==='Edit') {

           formData.append('_method', 'PATCH')
          }
                axios[this.method](this.store, formData).then(function(response) {
                    vm.$route.push('/list')
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'errors', error.response.data)
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use the debugger to figure out what is `undefined`.

Comment: `error.response` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the errors in the code,
there are several errors:

1.the line code vm.$route.push('/list'), generates an error for which the response.data property is not defined

2.the parameter that receive the  function push() is the problem,i had to change '/list' for a variable redirect:'list'

```
    <template>
    <div class="row center-element">
    <h1 class="pink-text center-align">{{title}}</h1>
    <form class="col s12 m12 " @submit.prevent="save">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix  light-blue-text">pets</i>
          <input id="name" type="text" class="validate" v-model="form.name">
          <label for="name">name</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="file-field input-field col s12 m12">
            <i class="material-icons prefix  light-blue-text">image</i>
            <input  id='image' type="file">
          <div class="file-path-wrapper ">
            <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row right-align">
        <button class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light light-blue " type="submit" name="action">
          <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
        </button>
        <router-link to="/" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light light-blue ">
          <i class="material-icons right">cancel</i>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
        data() {
            return{
            title:'Create',
            store: '/admin/animals',
                    method: 'post',
                form:{},
                errors:'',
                msm:'',
            redirect:'/'

            }

        },
        beforeMount() {
            if(this.$route.meta.mode === 'edit') {
                this.title = 'Edit'
                this.form.name =  this.$route.params.name
                this.store = 'animals/' + this.$route.params.id
                this.method = 'post'
            }
        },  
        methods:{
            save(){
                let vm = this
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('name',this.form.name)
                formData.append('image',image.files[0])
          if (this.title==='Edit') {

           formData.append('_method', 'PATCH')
          }
                axios[this.method](this.store, formData).then(function(response) {
                     Vue.set(vm.$data,'msm',response.data)
                  vm.$router.push(vm.redirect)
                }).catch(function(error) {
                    Vue.set(vm.$data, 'errors', error)
                })
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```